# Trying to use react Link within ajax success function

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am doing a simple app with react and flask. At this moment i am trying to implement the routing, with react-router, of a successful registration. I planned on doing this inside the ajax success function but i am struggling a bit.

```
handleSubmit:function(evt){

var data = {
  client: this.state.client,
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
    contact:this.state.contact
};  

evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/api/v1/register",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success:function(result){
      if(result.result == "That account already exists"){
        $("div.notification").html(result.result).show();
      }
      else if(result.result == "You didnt choose a user type"){
        $("div.notification").html(result.result).show();
      }
      else{
        console.log(result.result);
      **I tried Link to and push.history.pushState and it didnt work**
      }
    },
    error:function(){
      console.log("error with ajax");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Which version of React Router.. 2? I think you just do `browserHistory.push('/path')` https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

Comment: browserHistory.push worked! Thanks!